# cal: Indexer for recurring events not working

Tags: typo3, cal

cal 1.11.1 in TYPO3 7.6.22

the backand module cal indexer is working as expected, all recurring events will bi written in the database.

but the scheduler task Indexer for recurring events (cal) does not work. I filled out with all necessairy data: Folder with cal data, page with calendar plugin, index start and stop. When i manuelly start the indexer i get this error:

Execution of task "Indexer for recurring events (cal)" failed with the following message: PHP Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /typo3_src-7.6.22/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/ContentObject/ContentObjectRenderer.php line 824

When i change the version to the last master in git, the error message is gone but the task does nothing.

Any idea? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my fault ... but perhaps it is interesting for others because it nearly is a kind of a trap ...

You have to give the scheduler the date or the period, e.g. -1 years and +1 years. I wrote in the second line + 1 years (see the blank between + and 1 ... ) This tiny fault results in the error message because the time period was not defined. Well ...

Now it works.